# Can I get valgrind to tell me _which_ value is uninitialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, valgrind

I ran `valgrind` on some code as follows:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./test
```

It returns the following error:

```
==24860== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24860==    at 0x4081AF: GG::fl(M const&, M const&) const (po.cpp:71)
==24860==    by 0x405CDB: MO::fle(M const&, M const&) const (m.cpp:708)
==24860==    by 0x404310: M::operator>=(M const&) const (m.cpp:384)
==24860==    by 0x404336: M::operator<(M const&) const (m.cpp:386)
==24860==    by 0x4021FD: main (test.cpp:62)
==24860==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==24860==    at 0x4C2EBAB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==24860==    by 0x40653F: GODA<unsigned int>::allocate_new_block() (goda.hpp:82)
==24860==    by 0x406182: GODA<unsigned int>::GODA(unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) (goda.hpp:103)
==24860==    by 0x402A0E: M::init(unsigned long) (m.cpp:63)
==24860==    by 0x403831: M::M(std::initializer_list<unsigned int>, MO const*) (m.cpp:248)
==24860==    by 0x401B56: main (test.cpp:31)
```

So line 71 has an error. OK, great. Here are the lines leading up to line 71 of `po.cpp` (line 71 is last):

```
DEG_TYPE dtk = t.ord_deg();
DEG_TYPE duk = u.ord_deg();
bool searching = dtk == duk;
NVAR_TYPE n = t.nv();
NVAR_TYPE k = 0;
for (/* */; searching and k < n; ++k) { // this is line 71
```

OK, so *which* value of line 71 is uninitialized?

- certainly not `k`;
- I manually checked (= "stepping through `gdb`") that `t`'s constructor initializes the value that is returned by `t.nv()`, so certainly not `n` (in fact `n` is set to 6, the correct value);
- `searching` is determined by `dtk` and `duk`, but I also manually checked that `t`'s and `u`'s constructors initialize the values that are returned by `.ord_deg()` (in fact both `dtk` and `duk` are set to 3, the correct value).

I'm at a complete loss here. Is there some option that will tell `valgrind` to report *which precise value* it thinks is uninitialized?

**Update**

In answer to one question, here is line 61 of `test.cpp`:

```
M s { 1, 0, 5, 2, 0 };
```

So it constructs using an initializer list. Here's that constructor:

```
M::M(
    initializer_list<EXP_TYPE> p, const MO * ord
) {
  common_init(ord);
  init_e(p.size());
  NVAR_TYPE i = 0;
  last = 0;
  for (
       auto pi = p.begin();
       pi != p.end();
       ++pi
  ) {
    if (*pi != 0) {
      e[last] = i;
      e[last + 1] = *pi;
      last += 2;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  ord->set_data(*this);
}
```

Here's the data in the class, adding comments showing where it's initialized:

```
NVAR_TYPE n;    // init_e()
EXP_TYPE * e;   // common_init()
NVAR_TYPE last; // common_init()
DEG_TYPE od;    // common_init(), revised in ord->set_data()
const MO * o;   // common_init()
MOD * o_data;   // common_init(), revised in ord->set_data()
```

Comment: DId You test w/o code optimizations? With it Valgrind can give a lot of false positives

Comment: It's the value allocated at "goda.hpp:82".

Comment: Is `t` properly initialized here? If you "saw" that it was in debug mode, you might have assumed that uninitialized memory (which is usually zero-initialized in debug mode) looked initialized. Can you show `test.cpp:31`?

Comment: One of the design goals of Valgrind is no false positives. They can happen, especially if you are using an out of date version of Valgrind. An issue with your code is more likely.

Comment: @bartop The code is compiled as `g++ -O0 -g` so it should be unoptimized.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, `t` is initialized properly. I'm at work & this is a personal project; I'll see if I can get `test.cpp:31` up here later. However, I can definitely say that it isn't merely zero-initialized; I wrote the constructor for it and I verified that the constructor runs and initializes all values.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I'm using whatever Fedora 28 offers, which I'd imagine is pretty up-to-date. I don't _think_ it's a problem in my code, but that is why I want to know which value is considered uninitialized.

Comment: "Is there some option that will tell valgrind to report which precise value it thinks is uninitialized?" No, see Valgrind manual for `--track-origins` http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.options: `For uninitialised values originating from a heap block, Memcheck shows where the block was allocated.`

Comment: @ks1322 Make it an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there some option that will tell valgrind to report which precise
>   value it thinks is uninitialized?

The best you can do is to use `--track-origins=yes` (you already using this option). Valgrind will tell you only approximate location of uninitialised values (origin in terms of Valgrind), but not exact variable name. See [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.options) for `--track-origins`:

> When set to yes, Memcheck keeps track of the origins of all
>   uninitialised values. Then, when an uninitialised value error is
>   reported, Memcheck will try to show the origin of the value. An origin
>   can be one of the following four places: a heap block, a stack
>   allocation, a client request, or miscellaneous other sources (eg, a
>   call to brk).
>
> For uninitialised values originating from a heap block, Memcheck shows
>   where the block was allocated. For uninitialised values originating
>   from a stack allocation, Memcheck can tell you which function
>   allocated the value, but no more than that -- typically it shows you
>   the source location of the opening brace of the function. So you
>   should carefully check that all of the function's local variables are
>   initialised properly.

Comment: In the original question, --track-origins was already used. That indicates where the uninitialized value was created, not what variable was not initialized in the jump. But there is  a way to have more information than --track-origins, by examining the v-bits.

Answer (score 5):

You can use gdb+vgdb+valgrind to debug your program under valgrind.

Then, when valgrind stops on the error reported above, you can examine the
definedness of the variables you are interested in using the monitor request
'xb' or 'get_vbits' by asking the adress of the variable, and then examining
the vbits for the size of the variable.

For example:

```
p &searching
=> 0xabcdef
monitor xb 0xabcdef 1
=> will show you the value of searching and the related vbits.
```

For more details, see 'Debugging your program using Valgrind gdbserver and GDB' http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver
and 'Memcheck Monitor Commands' http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands

Comment: I would really like to mark this correct. Unfortunately, between posting my question and seeing your answer, I revised my code and the error seems to have disappeared. In any case, ks1322 has the correct answer I wanted, which was in terms of _`valgrind` itself_, not by attaching it to `gdb` or something similar. All the same, I appreciate this answer and voted it up.

Answer (score 3):

From the Valgrind [documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html),

> 4.2.2. Use of uninitialised values
>   ...
>
> **Sources of uninitialised data tend to be:**
>   - Local variables in procedures which have not been initialised, as in the example above.
>   - **The contents of heap blocks (allocated with malloc, new, or a similar function) before you (or a constructor) write something there.**

You have:

```
==24860==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==24860==    at 0x4C2EBAB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==24860==    by 0x40653F: GODA<unsigned int>::allocate_new_block() (goda.hpp:82)
```

So it is very likely that the `malloc` used by `GODA<unsigned int>::allocate_new_block()` is causing this error.

Comment: If You haven't noticed, the question contains --track-origis swithc

Comment: Oh, did not notice that.

Comment: @P.W @bartop So does the `--track-origins` switch mean it won't be a problem? I want to look at this later today and while I'm sure this is not the problem it would be nice to know for future reference.

Comment: That switch only slows down the memcheck.  I don't see other problems with that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use clang-tidy as an alternative to find uninitialized variables.
QtCreator 4.7 has full integration of clang-tidy, select "Clang-Tidy and Clazy" in the debug pane, press run, select the file(s) you want to test.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use QtCreator but I will see if I can use clang-tidy.

Comment: While `clang-tidy` found an interesting mistake, it was actually fixed somewhere else in the code, and in any case wasn't the cause of this one. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how memcheck works. In order to avoid generating excessive errors, uninitialized values don't get flagged until they have a possible impact on your code. The uninitialized information gets propagated by assignments.

```
// if ord_deg returns something that is uninitialized, dtk and/or duk will be
// flagged internally as uninitialized but no error issued
DEG_TYPE dtk = t.ord_deg();
DEG_TYPE duk = u.ord_deg();
// again transitively if either dtk or duk is flagged as uninitialized then
// searching will be flagged as uninitialized, and again no error issued
bool searching = dtk == duk;
// if nv() returns something that is uninitialized, n will be
// flagged internally as unintialized
NVAR_TYPE n = t.nv();
// k is flagged as initialized
NVAR_TYPE k = 0;
// OK now the values of searching and n affect your code flow
// if either is uninitialized then memcheck will issue an error
for (/* */; searching and k < n; ++k) { // this is line 71
```

Comment: I understand how memcheck works, but as you point out, there are at least two potential candidates in the line that is flagged. In a lot of situations there could be many more candidates. Surely `valgrind` could tell me _which_ of those candidates is the offending party.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at wrong stack trace.

Valgrind tells you that uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation:

```
==24860==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==24860==    at 0x4C2EBAB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==24860==    by 0x40653F: GODA<unsigned int>::allocate_new_block() (goda.hpp:82)
==24860==    by 0x406182: GODA<unsigned int>::GODA(unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) (goda.hpp:103)
==24860==    by 0x402A0E: M::init(unsigned long) (m.cpp:63)
==24860==    by 0x403831: M::M(std::initializer_list<unsigned int>, MO const*) (m.cpp:248)
==24860==    by 0x401B56: main (test.cpp:31)
```

You can omit a few top stack frames from third party library code, because it is less likely that the error is in third party code. You should look more closely at this stack frame, which appears to be your code:

```
==24860==    by 0x402A0E: M::init(unsigned long) (m.cpp:63)
```

Most likely uninitialized variable should be in `m.cpp:63` line of code.

Comment: Thanks; I think I did look at that line, but I will look at this later today when I get home.

Comment: OK, I looked at it. That just calls a custom memory allocator. I've been testing & running that on lots of programs with no problem, so that's not it.